# Why the $R_{\xi}$-contribution to the Lagrangian disappears when computing physical observables?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, gauge

In QED for example, you add the term $$\mathcal{L}_{GF}=-\frac{1}{2\xi}(A_{\mu}A^{\mu})^{2}$$ so you can compute the photon propagator. The question is basically, why you can compute physical observables where at the beginning a $\xi$-dependence appears, and the physical observable ends up with no such dependence, and it doesn't matter whether you choose 't Hooft-Feynman gauge $(\xi=1)$ or Unitary gauge $(\xi=0)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Independence of [gauge-fixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing) is perhaps easiest to understand in the [BRST formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BRST_quantization). It turns out that all of the gauge-fixing (including the [$\xi$-parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#R.CE.BE_gauges)) can be tucked away inside a BRST-exact part of the action, where it cannot affect BRST-invariant (=physical) observables, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/39096/2451).
2. For proofs that does not use the BRST formulation, see e.g. Refs 1-2.

References:

1. M.E. Peskin & D.V. Schroeder, *An Intro to QFT,* 1995; section 9.4.
2. M. Srednicki, *QFT,* 2007; chapter 71. A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).